# Apply a loader to only one file in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp

I'm new to webpack. I have been using gulp until now and trying to migrate to webpack.

In my *.gulpfile* I have:

```
var preProcess = require('gulp-preprocess');

gulp.src('app/config/app.constants.js')
.pipe(preProcess({
  context: {
    NODE_ENV: options.env
  }
}))
```

I have the following lines in *app/config/app.constants.js* that need to be removed in production:

```
//@if NODE_ENV='development'
AppConstants.api = 'https://localhost:333/api';
AppConstants.webRoot = 'http://localhost:222';
//@endif
```

I am trying to accomplish this in *wepack.config.js*:

```
if (!isDev) {
    config.module.rules.push([
        {
            test: ???, // Can't figure out what to put here
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|\.spec\.js)/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'webpack-strip-block',
                    options: {
                        start: '@if NODE_ENV='development'',
                        end: '@endif'
                    }
                }]
        }
    ])
}
```

Two questions: How do I test for a single file? Is this the right way to replace [gulp-preprocess](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-preprocess)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply a loader to a single file, use `include` instead of `exclude`. This is whitelisting instead of blacklisting. You don't need to use `test` at all. For example...

```
{
    include: 'path/to/your/file',
    use: [{
        loader: 'webpack-strip-block',
        options: {
            start: '@if NODE_ENV='development'',
            end: '@endif'
        }
   }]
}
```

Comment: Had to do `include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/your/file')`. In the end this loader did not work for my problem because it only works with `*/` type comments not `//`